# TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is the code that is giving me an error:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header';
import Todo from './components/Todo';

class App extends Component {
  state: {
    list: [
      {
        title: "Take out trash",
        completed: false,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        title: "Take dog for walk",
        completed: false,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        title: "Doctor appointment",
        completed: false,
        id: 3
      }
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header number={this.state.list.length} />
        <Todo/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

The message says it couldn't read 'this' when I was passing in the array as a prop to header. Aren't am I allowed to do this though? Why is the keyword 'this' undefined if its in a class component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the initial state incorrectly.

It should be:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    list: [
      {
        title: "Take out trash",
        completed: false,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        title: "Take dog for walk",
        completed: false,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        title: "Doctor appointment",
        completed: false,
        id: 3
      }
    ];
  }
```

Alternatively you can set it in the constructor method but this will achieve the same thing

Answer (score 2):

It's `state = { }` not `state: { }`.

Answer (score 1):

In your post title, you mention "list" is throwing the error, not "this". The underlying issue will be different depending on which one you meant. I suspect, `this.state` is undefined and therefor `this.state.list` throws an error, so my answer is based on that assumption until clarified.

I generally declare initial state in a `constructor` e.g.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header';
import Todo from './components/Todo';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      list: [
        {
          title: "Take out trash",
          completed: false,
          id: 1
        },
        {
          title: "Take dog for walk",
          completed: false,
          id: 2
        },
        {
          title: "Doctor appointment",
          completed: false,
          id: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header number={this.state.list.length} />
        <Todo/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

I've used your state declaration in a react native app of my own and gotten the same error. Initializing state as I did above should fix it.